# Locking Excel View

Tags: excel, vba, dashboard

I have prepared an Excel Dashboard which goes from column A to column N. And when I open the file, my Dashboard fits completely on my screen and I can view everything on the Dashboard. But when I send my file to someone else, they have their own view. Like one can see column till R and other can see till column K only. This is making my Dashboard unfit to share because it's not perfectly aligned for view to everyone. Is there a way I can lock this so that everyone using this Dashboard can see the same cell (Rows and Columns) I see?

Thanks

Comment: Everyone runs their screen at different resolutions and different magnifications, so no. There is no way to just "make it fit for everyone" - Your best option is to make it fit on the lowest resolution and people running at a higher resolution will see blank space. Or you can teach people how to zoom it according to their display.

Comment: Thanks @braX . I knew deep down that it's not possible but I didn't want to leave any stone unturned.

Answer (score 0):

I had an workbook as a dashboard, this is the code I use and it works. The name of sheet is "Dash".

The code is not in a module but in worksheet. Hope it works for you too.

```
Sheets("Dash").Activate
Sheets("Dash").ScrollArea = "A1:AB39"
Do
If ActiveWindow.Zoom <> 100 Then
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
End If
DoEvents
Loop While True
```

Comment: I'm not clear how this answers the actual question. The code just seems to set (and keep setting) the Zoom to 100 which isn't what the question asks. Perhaps you can add some context as to how you believe this answers the question?